# Remove-Appxpackage stuck

Tags: powershell, windows-11, dropbox

Windows 11, trying to uninstall preinstalled Dropbox (`DropboxOEM`) in Elevated PowerShell session:
`Get-AppxPackage -All *dropbox* | Remove-AppxPackage -AllUsers`
It gets stuck.

When I close the running session and open a new one, `Get-AppxPackage -All *dropbox*`, it still returns DropboxOEM package where it shows it is not installed for any user.

How to completely remove the DropboxOEM Appx?

Comment: Dropbox being a UWP application would be a shock, have you looked, in Add/Remove applications and tried to uninstall it there?

Comment: It isn't available, at least after what I have done.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with checking if it's a provisioned app, and if so, removing it:
`Get-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online | ogv -PassThru | Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -AllUsers`

Often times the Remove-Appx* cmdlets will provide an ActivityId string in the error message (in your case, it doesn't sound like you were gifted with an error message in the console), which can be used with the [Get-AppxLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxlog?view=windowsserver2019-ps) cmdlet's `-ActivityID` parameter.

You could also try peeking at the event logs in:

- Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > AppXDeployment-Server
- Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > AppXDeployment
- Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows > AppXPackagingOM

To [Ramhound](https://superuser.com/users/83283/ramhound)'s point - the typical consumer Dropbox program isn't a Windows Store app and is normally removed via `appwiz.cpl` - but if it's not appearing there, you can look in the registry to see if it's listed as a subkey of:

- HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
- HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Since you're working with DropboxOEM, it might have a different uninstaller or method of removal.  If you strike out with the above, you can try searching the registry for "DropboxOEM" or attempt to reinstall DropboxOEM, then use Get-AppxPackage or Get-ProvisionedAppxPackage to get more details about it, like its installation path, etc.

Here are some more helpful links:

- Windows apps troubleshooting Microsoft website

  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/appxpkg/troubleshooting
- To download Windows Store app .appx or .msixbundle files for manual reinstallations

  - https://store.rg-adguard.net/
  - https://apps.microsoft.com/store/apps
- Reinstall built-in apps

  - https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3175-reinstall-re-register-apps-windows-10-a.html